# Connect from PowerShell to Function app with Azure AD Join device identity

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, azure-functions, microsoft-entra-id

i have an internal reporting application and i run it in system context?

I want to use the local azure ad identity to connect and authenticate to the app which is configured to Azure AD integration.

It looks like there is a certificate enrolled on the device from Azure AD Domain join - but how do I use the certificate to get a Token for the Function App?

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable Function App Authentication with Azure AD Joined App or Azure AD app. Refer the steps below:-

[image]

Add your Azure AD Certificate in the Key vault and give the Azure AD App access to the certificate via Access Policy or RBAC refer [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/security-features#controlling-access-to-key-vault-data).

**Then run the below code in the Powershell Function HTTP Trigger:-**

```
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

# Define your AppId, TokenURI, and Resource
$AppId = "xxxxb838-6d26a31435cb"
$TokenURI = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/7xxxxf3b-4425-a6b6-09b47643ec58/oauth2/token"
$Resource = "https://management.core.windows.net/"

# Define the URL of the certificate stored in Azure Key Vault
$CertificateUrl = "https://your-keyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/your-certificate-secret"

# Prepare the body request
$BodyRequest = @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    client_id = $AppId
    client_assertion_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer"
    client_assertion = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String((Get-AzKeyVaultCertificateOperation -VaultName "your-keyvault" -CertificateName "your-certificate-name").Result)
    resource = $Resource
}

$AccessToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $TokenURI -Body $BodyRequest

# Now you can make the request to list all resources
$SubscriptionId = "6912d7a0-bc28-459a-9407-33bbba641c07"

$RequestURI = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resources?api-version=2021-04-01"

$Headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer " + $AccessToken.access_token
}

$ResourceRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $RequestURI -Headers $Headers

# Return the results as a response
$Response = @{
    StatusCode = 200
    Body = $ResourceRequest.value | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

Refer this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587054/how-to-authenticate-to-an-azure-function-using-function-auth-or-azure-ad-service) for the same scenario.